# How to speed up synchronizing json data from the server using json parser in android? 

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

## **Sync data from the server using json parser**

I have developed android application for offline concept.When internet connected more than 4000 records synchronized from the server. If i add only one data in the server. when i do second time synchronizing, that particular data to be synchronize from the server.My problem is when i do second time synchronizing data it took same time as first time synchronizing. how to avoid this,please advice me.
  Synchronizing working fine. But if i press the sync button second time. whole data can be synchronizing again. Please explain in detail. I have little bit idea i don't know whether it is correct or not.

### **My suggestion:**

Flag to be set in the server side and client side. If data synchronized flag to be set as 0. if data newly synchronized it should be set as 1. 
 if data loss. unfortunatly data cache cleared in application. how to do this?. please explain me.

Comment: dont use a boolean flag like you suggested.  perhaps use a date variable and compare with that.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE)
Here a googler explain how to build REST applications - there is a lot of usefull thing about sync.

If you build server and client by youw own - you can store timestamp of the last connection and each time you synchronize you pass this time to the server and depend on it you can pass only modified columns (you have to store timeStamp of modification for data or list of modified columns from key timestamps)

Comment: Actually my sync is working fine. But it takes 6.5 minutes for synchronizing 650kb of data. Is there any way to make sync faster. The given video have no examples. Can you explain in depth?

Comment: You can create you own local data base that contains all of the information and when you get data for your UI you will take it from local db. Sometimes you can check for updates each portion of data. For example if you have adress book you can display all users from local db then chekc for updates and then update your UI. And you have not to sync all of your data, only check for updates. Maybe your data is updating very often - you will have to update all of it each time, i don't now your app and your data =)